# What is the intuitive interpretation of the transpose compared to the inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, intuition, transpose

I've been thinking about this question already for a long time and I've just encountered it again in the following lemma:

$$f(x) = g(Ax + b) \implies \nabla f = A^T \nabla g(Ax + b) $$

This lemma makes intuitive sense if you think of it as taking the $x$ to the space $Ax$, calculating the gradient and then taking the result back to the original space. But why is "taking the result back" realised as $A^T$ and not $A^{-1}$?

By doing the calculations you get $A^T$, no doubt, but I always expect an inverse. In general, when should I expect a transpose and when an inverse? Where are they similar and where do they differ?

Comment: Think about the 1-dimensional case: if $f(x) = g(ax+b)$, then $f'(x) = g'(ax+b)a$, not $g'(ax+b)/a$.  So it can't be the inverse; it must be the transpose.

Comment: Also, the row matrix $\mathrm{D}f = (\nabla{f})^\top$ is more fundamental than the column matrix $\nabla{f}$.  So you should be thinking $\mathrm{D}f(x) = \mathrm{D}g(Ax+b)A$ to begin with; then you can explicitly take the transpose of each side, if you must, to get $\nabla{f}(x) = A^\top\nabla{g}(Ax+b)$.  But fundamentally, it's not about the transpose *or* the inverse.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We usually see matrices as linear transformations. The inverse of $A$, when it exists, means simply "reversing" what $A$ does as a function. The transpose originates in a different point of view.

So we have vector spaces $X,Y$, and $A:X\to Y$ is linear. For many reasons, we often look at the linear functionals on the space; that way we get the *dual*
$$
X^*=\{f:X\to\mathbb R:\ f\ \text{ is linear}\},
$$
and correspondingly $Y^*$. Now the map $A$ induces a natural map $A^*:Y^*\to X^*$, by 
$$
(A^*g)(x)=g(Ax).
$$
In the particular case where $X=\mathbb R^n$, $Y=\mathbb R^m$, one can check that $X^*=X$ and $Y^*=Y$, in the sense that all linear functionals $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ are of the form $f(x)=y^Tx$ for some fixed $y\in\mathbb R^n$. 
In this situation   $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, and the matrix of $A^*$ is the transpose of $A$.

Comment: You're the only one who answered my question. I wasn't asking about how to derive the formula, but everyone tried to derive it for me. You actually gave me insight into where the transpose comes from. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help. The whole thing is more visible in more abstract spaces than $\mathbb R^n$. In particular the adjoint plays a big role when dealing with HIlbert spaces and their operators. And the star in "C$^*$-algebra", for instance, comes from the notation for the adjoint.

Comment: Just to add a little bit, you can then treat $\nabla f(x)$ as a linear function, whose value $[\nabla f(x)](y)$ at $y$ is the dot product of $y$ and the gradient. In particular, the gradient is the function for which $g(x) = f(x_0) + [\nabla f(x_0)](x)$ is the best affine approximation of $f$ at $x_0$. Then $f(Ax_0) + [\nabla f(Ax_0)](Ax) = f(Ax_0) + [A^* \nabla f(Ax_0)](x)$ is the best linear approximation of $f(Ax)$ at $x_0$. The formula in the question is just the matrix representation of this.

Answer (score 10):

Something weird is going on here. I'm assuming $g: \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R$ and say $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix. Let $\mathcal a(x): \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m, x \mapsto Ax + b$ be the corresponding affine transformation, so that $f = g \circ a$. The chain rule says $Df(x) = Dg(a(x)) Da(x)$.

The Jacobian realization of $Dg$ is $\nabla g$ and is an $1\times m$ matrix (row vector), while the Jacobian for $a$ is $A$, an $m \times n $ matrix. The dimensions all agree, since this would make $\nabla f$ a $1\times n$ matrix, which agrees with the notion that the derivative of $f$ is a linear map $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$.

So what I suspect is happening is some identification of $\mathbb R^n$ with its dual space under the Euclidean inner product; that is, you're realizing the gradient as a column vector instead of a row vector. The transpose is precisely the way this is done. If $T: V \to W$ is a linear transformation, then its adjoint is $T^\dagger: W^* \to V^*$. But under the Euclidean inner product, you can identify $\mathbb R^n \cong (\mathbb R^n)^*$, so
$$ (\nabla g(a(x)) A)^T = A^T [\nabla g(a(x))]^T = A^T \nabla g(a(x))$$
where we're abusing notation by identifying the row vector $\nabla g$ with the column vector $\nabla g$. This hidden identification is likely what is confusing you.

Comment: I really wish that we could just teach that the gradient is a row vector in multivariable calculus from the beginning. This confusion is just not necessary, and exacerbates the process of learning about the Jacobian (which is basically a "column vector of gradients"). I understand why this isn't practical, though.

Comment: @Ian I got yelled at once by a very senior faculty member for defining the derivative of the map $g: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ as row vector, rather than distinguishing the linear transformation from its Jacobian representation. This was in a non-advanced course :S

Comment: @Ian Just curious. Why isn't that practical?

Comment: @user1551 There's no way to require all multivariable students to have enough familiarity with linear algebra to really understand the difference between row vectors and column vectors.

Comment: @Ian I wish we could stop talking about _row or column vectors entirely_, and instead start from abstract vector spaces and their dual spaces.

Comment: @leftaroundabout This is ideal, but dealing with higher order derivatives becomes a bit nasty don't you think? If $\mathcal L^n(V,W)$ are the $n$-linear maps from $V$ to $W$, then even the second derivative requires that students are familiar with the isomorphism $\mathcal L^1(V, \mathcal L^1(V,W)) \cong \mathcal L^2(V,W)$, and that's probably asking a bit much when most students have little linear algebra, let alone multilinear algebra.

Answer (score 8):

Notice using the chain rule that
$$D_p g(Av+b)=\langle\nabla g(Ap+b),Av\rangle=\langle A^T\nabla g(Ap+b),v\rangle.$$
Now compare to $D_pf(v)=\langle\nabla f(p),v\rangle$.

Answer (score 4):

Here you are not "taking the result back to the original space", you are chaining transforms.

If you think of a linear transform applied to a vector, it's a bunch of *dot products*, of the *rows* of the array by the *column* vector and

$$\vec x\cdot\vec y\equiv x^Ty.$$

Answer (score 4):

Taking the **directional derivative** of $f (\mathrm x) := g (\mathrm A \mathrm x + \mathrm b)$ in the direction of $\rm v$ at $\rm x$,

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f (\mathrm x + h \mathrm v) - f (\mathrm x)}{h} = \langle \nabla g (\mathrm A \mathrm x + \mathrm b), \mathrm A \mathrm v \rangle = \langle \mathrm A \mathrm v, \nabla g (\mathrm A \mathrm x + \mathrm b) \rangle = \langle \mathrm v, \mathrm A^\top \nabla g (\mathrm A \mathrm x + \mathrm b) \rangle$$

and, thus, the **gradient** of $f$ is

$$\nabla f (\mathrm x) = \mathrm A^\top \nabla g (\mathrm A \mathrm x + \mathrm b)$$

Comment: Essentially my answer given two hours before ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe When I wrote my answer, yours had not yet been posted. You can accuse me of not checking other answers before posting mine, but you cannot accuse me of plagiarism.